# Is there a way to get NSManagedObjectContext without having to calling my AppDelegate every time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uikit, sdk

I created an app from a Xcode template and selected "Core Data" as an option, so all of the Core Data delegates and main methods would be included in the AppDelegate files.

Now, every time I have to get the context in order to use Core Data, I'm using the following code:

```
MovieCatalogAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MovieCatalogAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
```

Is there anyway to get the managedObjectContext without needing to call directly to the MovieCatalogAppDelegate? I want to make it a generic call so my data files aren't necessarily bound to MovieCatalogAppDelegate.h. Basically, I am trying to decouple the code and make things more dynamic without need to know direct names.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few different options.

1. You could move your Core Data support code into a class other than your app delegate. Make it a singleton, if you'd like.
2. You could pass in your managed object context as a property of each view controller.
3. If you have an `NSManagedObject` that you're already passing around, you can get the `NSManagedObjectContext` from the `managedObjectContext` of said object.

There are some ideas in [this article](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/01/07/passing-around-a-nsmanagedobjectcontext-on-the-iphone/) on CIMGF.

Answer (score 4):

The official answer (Apple Documentation) is that you should have a pointer to the managedObjectContext on every single one of the classes that will use it and pass it along any other objects that need to use it.

You can set it as a property of your UIViewControllers (or any other object) and set it upon creation; so on your code you will just need to call:

`self.managedObjectContext`

Instead of going all the way to the delegate.

If you need more info just comment and I will update the answer.

Comment: How would you do this with tab bar controllers and navigation controllers since apple recommends against sub classing them.

Comment: You would solve it in the same way because the navigation controller and the tabBar controller dont actually need a reference to the data. You would set it as a property of the view controllers INSIDE the nav controller and/or tab bar controller, which is what you subclass.